# Why won't hibernation work on this Ubuntu-certified laptop?

Tags: dell, hibernate, inspiron, hardware-certification

I recently bought the dell Inspiron 3542 (Ubuntu-certified), it came preloaded with Ubuntu 12.04, I did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 (erased everything).

When I try `sudo pm-hibernate` the computer shuts down and when I start it, my apps won't reopen.

I have 4GB of ram and a 4GB swap partition that is never used(shows 0.0% in system monitor), I think that's because I never overloaded the laptop.

Note: when i login after a failed hibernation, i get this window :

[image]

Comment: What apps won't open? Any of them?

Comment: All of them, it acts like any normal boot with the addition of a bug report window showing up, i will add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know hibernation is disabled in Ubuntu 14.04. Follow these steps to enable it:

Type the below command in your terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Fill the file with the following lines:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

Save and exit.

Hibernation will be enabled after reboot. If you can not see the hibernate option in your menu, run this command;

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

It is better to have a swap partition that is as large as your available RAM for hibernation to work smoothly.  Refer the Ubuntu [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) for details.

In addition you might also have to install `pm-utils`

Comment: Clicking on hibernate in the menu give the same results as `pm-hibernate`

Comment: yes, it is same as `pm-hibernate`, but did you enable hibernate in the first place? And is the above fix working for you?

Comment: Yes, i enabled hibernation, and no it did not change anything, still same problem.

Comment: how about  installing `pm-utils`?

Comment: i'll give it a try

Comment: it seems that `pm-utils` is already installed.